# Node.js Forever is not creating Log files

Tags: javascript, node.js, forever

2 nodejs scripts are being handled by `forever`. The system is using forever v0.11.1 and node v0.10.29

```
# forever list
info:    Forever processes running
data:        uid  command  script      forever pid   logfile                 uptime        
data:    [0] D34J userdown app/main.js 7441    10950 /root/.forever/D34J.log 0:2:31:45.572 
data:    [1] P0BX userdown app/main.js 11242   11261 /root/.forever/P0BX.log 0:2:20:22.157 
# forever logs 0
error:   undefined
# forever logs 1
error:   undefined
```

**Question:** Why are the log files created by `forever` missing? Restarting the 2 processes still doesn't create any log files...

The directory `/root/.forever` does not show the log files too!

```
# ls -la /root/.forever
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jul  4 11:37 .
drwx------ 8 root root 4096 Jul 10 13:24 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  259 Jul 10 19:34 config.json
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul  4 11:37 pids
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 10 17:12 sock
```

Comment: What command are you using to launch forever? And what operating system are you using?

Answer (score 5):

If you start your node process with `forever your_script.js` and don't specify a log file, `forever` will write your logs to the terminal (or `cmd` on Windows). The log file that is shown when you run `forever list` or `forever logs` does not reflect reality, since it's not created in that scenario. But if you specify log files, following the options:

```
-l  LOGFILE      Logs the forever output to LOGFILE
-o  OUTFILE      Logs stdout from child script to OUTFILE
-e  ERRFILE      Logs stderr from child script to ERRFILE
```

, like `forever -l console.log -e error.log your_script.log`, they will be created.

If you want `forever` to automatically create a log file for you, you have to start your script as a daemon, with `forever start your_script.js`. In this case, you can also specify your log files.

In the [docs](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever#using-forever-from-the-command-line) page you can see all the command line options.

Comment: `forever start bin/www -e logs/error.log -l logs/logs.log` not creating any files.. any idea whats wrong?

Answer (score 4):

To answer Shreejibawa (since I can't comment yet)...

forever is very sensitive to the order of the arguments.  Take a look at their documentation and notice that the options must come before the script.

```
forever [action] [options] SCRIPT [script-options]
```

Instead of: `forever start bin/www -e logs/error.log -l logs/logs.log`

Try: `forever start -e /path/to/logs/error.log -l /path/to/logs/logs.log your_script.js`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in OSX. In OSX (at least), the command `forever app.js` starts the forever **process** in the foreground and doesn't write the log to file, even when -l and -e are provided. In this case, `forever list` lists the file even though it isn't there and `forever logs i` produces `error:   undefined`.

When the forever **DAEMON** is started using `forever start app.js`, the log files do appear and can be viewed using `forever logs i`.